# SEO aspect about client side routing with angularjs or vuejs

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2, seo, angular-routing

Using a client side routing server side doesn't forge entire page to serve a client, but datas are downloaded from webapp "on demand".
So, in this scenario, if you see html code you could see something like this below:

```
<body>
    <div class="blah">{{content}}</div>
</body>
```

I know that prerender strategy can be used and i think that probably google crawler is very smarty and can see contents anyway, but the question is:

is it good this approach on seo side?

Using prerender strategy server needs to generate page with content. Could be that a penalty in page speed factor?

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Voting to close, but adding a comment: If SEO is important to your app, then you should definitely consider looking at server rendering. It also helps with link previews (open graph metadata, twitter cards, etc) so your app links look so much cooler when pasted into other apps/services. I'd worry less about the the speed tradeoffs (if any) if the above things are important for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned google is pretty smart and from a recent experience, is able to fetch some of your site's static content even when using client-side rendering. However when it comes to client-side routing it's not quite there yet so if you need to have SEO, server side rendering frameworks like nuxt.js should be your go-to.

> but datas are downloaded from webapp "on demand"

The same thing applies when you do asynchronous fetches (download on demand as you've described it), imagine the data inside your `{{ content }}` was coming from an external API, as far as I'm concerned no crawler at this time is able to deal with this, so your content area would just be empty. So generally speaking, when SEO is an requirement, so is server-side rendering.

> Using prerender strategy server needs to generate page with content.
>   Could be that a penalty in page speed factor?

Yes and no. Load times will certainly go up a little, but when using client-side rendering, the client needs to render the page after loading it, so this time just gets shifted to your server. This applies again to asynchronous data fetching. The delivery of the site will take longer, but the data it has to fetch will already be there, so the client wont have to do it (SSR frameworks allow you to fetch data and render it before sending the site to the client). If you accumulate everything, there shouldn't be a huge difference in time from sending the request to actually seeing the rendered page in your browser.

Comment: Thank you @PhilipFeldmann for your response. I see nuxt.js and it seems a great solution, but i think that nuxt is only for server side applications javascript based. right?

Comment: @sergioska No. What Nuxt (and 'universal' in angular's case) does, it allows you pre-render some things on the server before delivering your SPA to the client. So you can do some data fetches, render an initial page and send this to the user. It also understands routing and delivers the correct entry page to the user. This is important for crawlers, because unlike users every crawl is a new request. A normal user will get a pre-rendered page, but from there on the entire navigation and data fetching will be client side. It's only a trick really to make it accessible for crawlers.

Comment: @sergioska So to sum it up: Nuxt only renders the initial request for the user. Everything else will still be on the client side, it'll feel exactly the same as a single page application.